# How to resolve changeset conflicts

Tags: version-control, tfs, changeset

I have a real time scenario where there is a one developer who created 3 change sets as in 1.1,1.2 & 1.3 and decides to checkin changeset 1.3.

Now the second developer checks out the code and writes his code and does CheckIn. The situation is 1st developer decides that he should not have checkedIn 1.3 instead checked IN 1.2 but if he checksIn 1.2, what ever the changes or coding that is done by the second developer is lost as he developed the code depending on changeset 1.3.

So the dependencies are effected and there is lot of code conflict. can any one tell me how to fix this? what are the different ways of fixing the situation and how do we achieve it? This is in TFS.

Comment: I deleted the older questions, since this one has new tags and title.  In the future, please just edit your question instead of posting a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

1. Assuming the first dev checked in 1.1, then 1.2 and then 1.3, you can do the following: Go back to 1.2, branch, and then merge the commits of the second dev to the new branch. Continue from there or commit the new branch onto the top of trunk.
2. Assuming that the first dev only checked in 1.3 at once and not the history: Let him create a reverse patch from 1.3 -> 1.2. Apply it to the result of the second dev's work, manually work out the conflicts.